# How to prevent `desktop-save-mode` from opening multiple windows?

Tags: init-file, buffers, window, desktop

I want to restart Emacs at the same cursor position in the file (or buffer) I was just working on.

In my Emacs config I have the following code to try and do this:

```lisp
(use-package desktop
      :straight nil
      ;;:defer 1
      :init
      ;; Automatically save and restore sessions
      ;; FIX: Replace hardcoded desktop-dirname with my-savefile-dir
      (setq desktop-dirname             "~/.emacs.d/desktop/"
        desktop-base-file-name      "emacs.desktop"
        desktop-base-lock-name      "lock"
        desktop-path                (list desktop-dirname)
        desktop-save                t
        desktop-files-not-to-save   "^$" ;reload tramp paths
        desktop-load-locked-desktop nil
        desktop-auto-save-timeout   30
        desktop-restore-reuses-frames nil
        desktop-buffers-not-to-save
        (concat "\\("
            "^nn\\.a[0-9]+\\|\\.log\\|(ftp)\\|^tags\\|^TAGS"
            "\\|\\.emacs.*\\|\\.diary\\|\\.newsrc-dribble\\|\\.bbdb"
            "\\)$"))
      (setq desktop-restore-eager 1)
      (desktop-save-mode 1)
      (desktop-read)
      :config
      (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'dired-mode)
      ;;(add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'Info-mode)
      ;;(add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'info-lookup-mode)
      (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'fundamental-mode))
```

**Note:** This is code updated slightly from the original post, but the issue still remains.

It seems to save the cursor in the given file if I exit.

However the problem is that when Emacs opens, it opens many buffers
in separate windows. Each Emacs window appears to be a clone of the others . This is confusing and not the intended outcome. Not sure what is causing this issue.

For example, if I was working on `file1.org` and left it at column 10, line 20, then
I want a single Emacs window to open in `file1.org` at column 10, line 20. I don't want multiple windows to open with any previously visited Dired buffers etc.

I can confirm that if I comment out the above code, the problem goes away, but so does the required effect, i.e., I no longer start at `file1.org` at the given location.

Here is a screenshot of the multiple windows that open when I startup Emacs.App (v28.1) on my macOS (Monterey v12.1):

[image]

I can clarify my settings further
if needed.

Comment: I'm not quite got your question, but maybe you can try `(setq desktop-restore-eager 1)` to restore only the frontmost buffer immediately.

Comment: @TianshuWang - thanks for your feedback. This didn't work. The main issue is that with the current setting above, multiple emacs windows open when I re-launch emacs. If I was last working in `file1.org` column 10, line 20, this is **exactly** where I would like emacs to have my cursor on startup. Right now it is opening up dired buffers etc, even though I tried to ignore them. Does that clarify better?

Comment: @TianshuWang I've added a screenshot to make it easier to see the issue. Three emacs windows open, when I would just like one window to open.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `emacs -Q` with your config like [this](https://pastebin.com/9m1T4RjT). Would you mind delete your desktop file and check with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @TianshuWang - Thanks for your efforts and suggestion. I tried to delete the `emacs.d/desktop/emacs.desktop` and `emacs.d/desktop/lock` files and restart. It did work as intended once. But since then I can't reproduce this even if I keep deleting these files and restarting. I've updated my config slightly in the original post. Is there some issue with the lock file setting?

Comment: Ok some progress. I deleted the `emacs.desktop` and `lock` files. But I noticed I was starting emacs from the terminal using `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app .`. The `.` at the end intended to start emacs in the current working directory. This messed up the desktop save startup!

Comment: So if I just now start emacs using `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app`, i.e., **without** the trailing `.`, it works as intended! However, is it possible to change the elisp above to be more robust to this? So if I accidentally use the trailing `.` command when launching emacs from the terminal, i.e., `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app .`, then the save desktop would just treat this as `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app` (without the trailing `.`)?

Comment: There is still no mess up with the trailing `.`. I really suggest you try `emacs -Q -l test.el` to test if it's something wrong with your config.